# Finding limit of a contractive sequence

Tags: cauchy-sequences

There is a sequence which I proved to be a contractive sequence, I have problem in finding its limit.
If $x_1 < x_2$ are arbitrary real numbers and $\displaystyle x_n = \frac{x_{n-1} + x_{n-2}}{2}$ for $n>2$. Find limit of $x_n$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple example of a second order homogenous linear recurrence relation with constant coefficients. There is a general formula for these: first start by finding the roots of the characteristic polynomial. This polynomial is obtained by substituting $a_n=x^n$ on the recurrence relation. After simplifying, one gets: $$x^2=\frac{x+1}{2} \rightarrow x=1,-\frac{1}{2}$$
Then the expression of $x_n$ is simply: $x_n=A(r_1)^n+B(r_2)^n=A(1)^n+B(-\frac{1}{2})^n$, because the two roots of the characteristic polynomial are different. You can then solve for $A$ and $B$ with the values of $x_1$ and $x_2$, as:

$$
\begin{cases}
x_1=A-\frac{1}{2}B \\
x_2=A+\frac{1}{4}B\\
\end{cases}
$$

For more on this try reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).

**EDIT**: Hope it is clearer now. I encourage you to read about the math behind this on the link above.

Comment: Pls explain it in more detail because I comfortable with this answer

Comment: As I said, the theory of why this works is too complex to explain here and simply not the point of this platform. Check the wikipedia link for a run through on that topic. I added some details to the answer. If you think it now answers your question, please accept it on the side.